# How do i fetch each foreach result from mysqli database

Tags: php, sql, database, foreach

How to send a foreach query into mysqli database?

I have tried:

```php
<?php
require("init.php");

$sql = "SELECT `item_name` FROM `books` WHERE `book`='1905515'";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $optionsArray[] = $record['item_name']; 
}

foreach ($optionsArray as $item) {
    $item="$item"; $sqli = "SELECT `code` FROM `promo` WHERE `code`='$item'";
    $query2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sqli);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)) {
        $name = $row["recharge"]; echo "$name"; 
    } 
}
?>
```

But I'm getting no results in output.

Comment: Your code is unclear. Please select it and press CTRL+K.

Comment: I dont have such option here!!

Comment: Edit your question and sort your code with the "{ } " tool when u select it.

Comment: @EniediMonday I've updated your code, could you approve it so its more readable

Comment: Thanks @praveen do you have any solution or idea to my code now?

Comment: Could add `var_dump($optionsArray), between `while` and `foreach`? and let us know if you get any results?

Comment: Yes i get result my first query is fine

Comment: This error might be because of `$item="$item"; ` line in your `foreach` loop. `$item` is accessible within the loop without that resetting. I recommend @Dimitri Yeung approach as you're not exhausting the server with multiple request.

Answer (score 0):

No need for a while loop, you can just `JOIN` the two tables like this:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM books AS b
INNER JOIN promo AS c ON b.item_name = c.code 
WHERE b.book='1905515';
```

Based on your code, you just need to join based on `item_name` from books table equal to `code` from the `promo` table. May be this is the issue and you should join based on a different columns.

You can run this query in mysql workbench or phpmyadmin to check the results before implementing it in your php pages.

Comment: @Demitri yeung I got am wrong syntax error,
unexpected '"', expecting
identifier (T_STRING) or variable
(T_VARIABLE) or number
(T_NUM_STRING)
 in the code <?php
require("init.php");
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT c.*

    FROM books AS b

    INNER JOIN promo AS c ON b.item_name = c.code 

    WHERE b.book='1905515''');
if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)
{
 $user = $row["recharge"];
 echo "$user";
}
?>

Comment: @EniediMonday I don't know PHP, but, I think you have something wrong in your php. Can you try the query only directly in mysql workbench or phpmyadmin??